# Одна таблица или несколько

Tags: php, база-данных, sql

Посоветуйте определиться. Как лучше хранить пользователей - в одной таблице это будут и клинты, и сотрудники, и админы? Или в отдельной для каждого?
Это ведь еще при авторизации нужно будет проверять сначала в одной таблице, есть ли такой пользователь, если нет, то проверять в другой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В идеале для таких целей у Вас должно быть минимум две, а оптимально четыре таблицы и с совершенно другой логикой.

Если у Вас одна таблица, то никакого разделения логики нет, и таблица в принципе имеет право на существование, но пользоваться ей неудобно и в дальнейшем, если планируется расширение возможностей, проблематично.

Ваш вариант с несколькими таблицами совсем не подходит. Только представьте, что будет, если пользователь сменит роль, у Вас добавиться новая роль (к примеру, корректор) или он должен иметь несколько ролей.

**Оптимальные вариант**

Первая таблица является главной и содержит данные идентификации, назовем ее users:

```
users
-- id
-- login
-- password
```

Это данные, к которым вы будете чаще других обращаться при проверке на вход.

Вторая таблица содержит роли пользователя (пользователь, админ, модератор, корректор, etc):

```
role
-- id
-- role
```

Третья таблица их связывает:

```
permission
-- id
-- users.id
-- role.id
```

Теперь вы можете составить запрос, который выберет роль (или роли) из этих таблиц.

Я так же упомянул четвертую таблицу, в ней лучше хранить информацию о пользователе. Просто потому, что к этим данным вы будете не так часто обращаться, как к таблице users, и их желательно выделить в отдельную таблицу.

```
userinfo
-- id
-- users.id
-- //другие поля
```

В итоге получается такая структура:

[image]

Из которой уже можно выбрать нужные данные запросом:

```
SELECT r.role FROM role r
JOIN permission p ON r.id = p.role_id
JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.login = 'Alex'
```

P.S. Несмотря на кажущееся усложнение структуры, такая модель имеет очень много преимуществ (контроль изменения данных, отделение логических структур, легкий рефакторинг, добавление новых возможностей) и лишена многих недостатков при использовании одной таблицы. Если хотите знать больше про преимущества, изучайте НФ и что они дают.

Comment: красавчик. +100500 в карму, что не поленился раздуплить

Comment: @Alex Krass Зачем для сущности `userinfo` создавать суроггатный ключ `id`, когда есть уже уникальный `user_id`? Я бы понял, если применялся [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) паттерн для реализации динамического набора атрибутов.

Comment: @Alex Krass, спасибо большое!

Comment: @romeo, в данном случае да, он тут не нужен. Это просто мои личные рабочие моменты просочились в ответ: у одного человека могут быть две различные личные карточки и user_id перестает быть уникальным.

Answer (score 3):

вам нужно создать две таблицы (или три). В одной роли пользователей, в другой сами пользователи с привязкой к айди роли (один к одному). Если одному пользователю будет присвоено несколько ролей, заводите третью промежуточную таблицу с отношением айди пользователя к айди роли (один к многим).

Answer (score 2):

Если брать ваш пример, то ***как вариант*** можно так

```
 - users
 - staff // или groups (как угодно)
 -  - user_admins // для сопоставления
 - clients
 - - user_clients // для сопоставления
```

Все изначально в таблице users. Если человек с id=10 должен быть админом, то (при условии, что группа администраторов в таблице groups имеет id=2) должна быть запись в user_admins где user_id=10 должен соответствовать group_id=2. Так же и с клиентами.

Answer (score 0):

Самый топорный метод- в одной таблице тоже можно всех, где и определены права для каждого. секретарь-3 бухи-2 админ-1

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже 4 таблицы. Просто так легче бывает восстановить...

Comment: До этого делал с категориями на несколько сайтов. Плохой способ.