# Как юзеру выводить информацию из другой таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Я учусь писать личный кабинет с выводом таблицы, которая берет данные из БД.
Каждому пользователю буду выдавать логин и пароль, после того как пользователь авторизовался, выходит таблица с его данными.

Как я это реализовал: Я создал таблицу "users", в которой были поля:

```
id_user
login_user
pass_user
name_user
data_user
summa_user
credit_user
dolg_us
staus_us
monthly_us
```

Показал более опытному разработчику, но он очень занятая персона, поэтому прошу помощи у Вас.
Он мне сказал, нужно сделать так:
создать 2 таблицы, в первой будет инфо о пользователе, то есть:

```
1 таблица users:
id_user
login_user
pass_user
name_user

2 таблица credit:
id_credit
data_credit
summa_credit
credit_credit
dolg_credit
staus_credit
monthly_credit
```

До этого момента я понял, а дальше у меня возникают вопросы:

Как после этого выводить каждому пользователю свои данные? То есть если я создам вторую таблицу и заполню ее, то всем пользователям будет выводится одна информация, а мне нужно, чтобы у каждого пользователя была своя информация, то есть по id. Если у первого пользователя id 2 (потому что у админа id-1), надо, чтобы информация у него была своя, со второй таблицы credit, id 1.

Я прошу не судить строго, так как не понимаю еще логики, просто прошу объяснить и, если можно, расписать поподробнее...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужное тебе хорошо описано в другом вопросе. [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400592/php-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE)

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит добавить в таблицу ещё один параметр "user_id", куда будете присваивать значение из таблицы users, и затем, когда вам нужно будет подтянуть значение из credit для users, то вы сможете это сделать.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = 1;
```

И затем

```
SELECT * FROM credit WHERE user_id = 1;
```