# Разработка БД для компьютерного магазина

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Всем доброго времени суток!

Прошу помощи с оптимизацией. Нарисовал схему БД (нарисована далеко не по правилам, но примерная суть ясна), создал все таблицы и колонки в PostgreSQL, начинаю заполнять и тут начинаются пляски с бубнами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке заполнить таблицу где есть вторичные ключи, постоянно вылезает ошибка в которой говорится о том, что вторичный ключ не может быть заполнен, ибо ссылка на первичный ключ исходной таблицы пуста. Грубо говоря: заполняя таблицу ***Оборудование***, "слон" ругается на вторичный ключ ***ID поставщика***, потому что в таблице ***Поставщик*** первичный ключ ***ID поставщика*** пустой. Начинаешь заполнять таблицу ***Поставщик*** он уже ругается на вторичный ключ ***ID оборудование*** ссылаясь на таблицу ***Оборудование*** - и так по замкнутому кругу...

В итоге я пришел к мысли, что у меня В КОРНЕ кривая реализация самой БД.
Вот. Прошу помочь разобраться. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуй почитать вот тут. Думаю немного прояснит ситуацию. [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400592/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в таблицах отношения многие ко многим, что есть зло. Если такая ситуация возникает необходимо выделить промежуточную таблицу которая бы реализовывала два отношения один ко многим.

```
Оборудование
| Eqipment_ID       | int          | PK       |
| EqType_ID         | int          | FK       |
| Eqipment_Name     | varchar(50)  |          |

Поставщик
| Producer_ID       | int          | PK       |
| Producer_Name     | varchar(50)  |          |
| Producer_Address  | varchar(50)  |          |
| Producer_Phone    | varchar(50)  |          |
| Producer_Mail     | varchar(50)  |          |

Конкретное оборудование
| CurEqipment_ID       | int          | PK       |
| Equipment_ID         | int          | FK       | -- ссылаемся на таблицу "Оборудование"
| Producer_ID          | int          | FK       | -- cсылаемся на таблицу "Поставщик"
| CurEqipment_Count    | int          |          |
| CurEqipment_Price    | float        |          |
| CurEqipment_Warranty | int          |          |
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам вообще в оборудовании ID поставщика и ID заказа и уж тем более ID компьютера?

У вас разве что таблица клиентов выполнена нормально с точки зрения ключей.

У вас проблема в рекурсивности зависимостей.

Подумайте что во что входит, а не, что вы будете запрашивать из таблицы, есть возможность сделать сложные запросы в базу с выборкой из нескольких таблиц.

Кроме того, как написал первый отвечавший, если у вас, например, несколько поставщиков к одному оборудованию и несколько типов оборудования относятся к одному поставщику вам нужна таблица для связей.